# Is it possible to keep packages installed on ubuntu when booting from DVD

Tags: boot, dvd, window

I have a machine running windows 7 and I boot Ubuntu from a DVD I prefer not to partition my hardrive for a dual boot so I picked the option of trying ubuntu. Is it possible to download packages like nmap and have them installed so that the next time I boot from dvd the package will already be installed. Yesterday I downloaded a few packages but I guess they are not saved. So I was wondering if there is a way to save the packages on dvd so they will always be available on boot.

Comment: A DVD is kinda tricky coz you will have to write data on it. Why don't you try a live USB, you can install and save packages there with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with a DVD, but you can install Ubuntu on a USB and set it up to have persistance.  Just read the wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent